# How to get private channel conversation of MS teams by using content search?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powershell-4.0, o365security-compliance

I have One Team and two public channels and two private channels in that.
Team -- Members(M1,M2,M3),
Private Channel 1 -- Members(M1,M2),
Private Channel 2 --  Members(M1,M3),
Public Channel 1  -- Members(M1,M2,M3),
Public Channel 2  -- -- Members(M1,M2,M3).

So Now i want to get "M2" Conversations and he is in Private Channel 1 and not in private channel 2.I am using Compliance search.
So now i want to get all the channel conversations which have "M2" is a member.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention We are looking into it

Comment: Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention We are looking into it

Comment: Could you please look at [List channel messages API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)?